# Replace block of lines using sed

Tags: linux, sed, replace

I have some trouble with sed: What I need to do is edit a config file using sed.
I want to replace a block of lines.

Here is my config file: file.php

```
$status = new GCollection('Status');
$sql = "SELECT status_id,nom from planning_status order by priorite asc";
$status->db_loadSQL($sql);
$smarty->assign('listeStatus', $status->getSmartyData());
// liste de tous les utilisateurs
$listeUsers = new GCollection('User');
```

Want to be

```
$status = new GCollection('Status');
$sql = "SELECT planning,nom from main_table order by priorite desc";
// liste de tous les utilisateurs
$listeUsers = new GCollection('User');
if($user->checkDroit('tasks_modify_own_task')) {
    $sql = " SELECT *
    FROM planning
}
```

I tried something like

```
RIGHT=$(cat <<- "EOF"
$status = new GCollection('Status');
$sql = "SELECT status_id,nom from planning_status order by priorite asc";
$status->db_loadSQL($sql);
$smarty->assign('listeStatus', $status->getSmartyData());
// liste de tous les utilisateurs
$listeUsers = new GCollection('User');
EOF
)

NEW=$(cat <<- "EOF"
$status = new GCollection('Status');
$sql = "SELECT planning,nom from main_table order by priorite desc";
// liste de tous les utilisateurs
$listeUsers = new GCollection('User');
if($user->checkDroit('tasks_modify_own_task')) {
    $sql = " SELECT *
    FROM planning
}
EOF
)


sed -i 's/$RIGHT/$NEW' file.php
```

This my error :

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 13: unterminated `s' command
```

Comment: And what is your code, and where are you having trouble? Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a smart way of doing multiline replacement with `sed`. Convert everything to hex!

```
to_hex() { xxd -p | tr -d '\n'; }
from_hex() { xxd -p -r; }
to_hex <file | sed "s/$(to_hex <<<"$RIGHT")/$(to_hex <<<"$NEW")/" | from_hex | sponge file
```

Note: [sponge](https://man.cx/sponge) is part of moreutils.

Comment: I see a bug in this, where the file has for example 4 bytes `0xaa, 0xbb, 0xaa, 0xbb` and we want to substitute `0xba, 0xab` for something. Then `sed` sees `aabbaabb` and substitutes `baab` which is not the intention. To be safer, it would be preferable to like add spaces after each hex byte `sed 's/../& /g'` in `to_hex`, so differentiate beginning and end of byte. The `xxd -p -c1 | tr '\n' ' '` looks nice for `to_hex`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed and bash):

```
a=$(sed -z 's/\n/\\n/g' <<<"$RIGHT")
b=$(sed -z 's/\n/\\n/g' <<<"$NEW")
sed -z "s/$a/$b/" file
```

The strings $RIGHT and $NEW contain newlines and these will terminate any sed command, these must be quoted in order for the substitution to take place. By forming new variables and using the `-z` option, multiple lines within a file may be matched and replaced/deleted.

N.B. By using surrounding the sed command by `"`'s it may be interpolated by the shell, this may cause unwanted side effects, beware!

Alternatively:

```
sed -z 's/'"$a"'/'"$b"'/g' file
```

Comment: First of all thank you for answering
I having the followed output
```sed: -e expression #1, char 206: unknown option to `s' ```
(I have fixed the b variable with $NEW)

Comment: Is there a `/` character in the NEW or RIGHT? They would have to be escaped too. Or just try unreadable character. `sed -z "s\x01$a\x01$b\x01"`